# Change org-priority faces when DONE

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, faces

Is there a way to change the color of `org-priority` face once the item is marked as `DONE`? Currently, the entire line aside from the item's priority gets grayed out once the item is marked as `DONE`.  [image: screenshot]

Comment: `org-mode` flat text files rely upon `org-set-font-lock-defaults` to colorize the done headings with the `org-headline-done` face -- the section with the comment `;; DONE` would need to be changed in order to affect the aforementioned files.  `org-agenda`, however, uses *text-properties* to place the `org-agenda-done` face at the specified locations instead of font-lock to colorize -- at first glance, several functions may need to be modified to achieve the desired affect.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I fully understand. From what I can tell, the priority tags are colorized based on the `org-priority` face. Couldn't one somehow give priority to `org-headline-done` so that it overrides the values assigned to `org-priority`? (I realize this question might be confused. I'm pretty new to Emacs.)

Comment: Perhaps the function `org-font-lock-add-priority-faces` could be tweaked to suit your needs.  I am unable to duplicate what is in the picture with a minimal working example, so I cannot examine any text-properties-at point, C-u C-x =, and so forth to be of further assistance ....  It may be helpful to update the question to specify which version of `org-mode` you are using.